# Twisted: Waiting for all deferreds to fire

Tags: python, twisted, trial

When i call DoSomething() method from my test method, i expect it to block on the yield in Connect() but it doesnt, it returns a not called yet deferred.

```
Class Foo:
    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def Connect(self):
        amqpConfig = AmqpConfig(self.config.getConfigFile())
        self.amqp = AmqpFactory(amqpConfig)

        try:
            # First Deferred
            d = self.amqp.connect()
            # Second Deferred
            d.addCallback(lambda ign: self.amqp.getChannelReadyDeferred()) 

            # Block until connecting and getting an AMQP channel
            yield d
        except Exception, e:
            self.log.error('Cannot connect to AMQP broker: %s', e)

    def DoSomething(self):
        c = self.Connect()
        # None of the deferreds were fired, c.called is False
```

How can i let it block till the second (and last) deferred is called ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `self.Connect()` in `DoSomething()` is *supposed* to return a not-yet-fired Deferred; that's how inlineCallbacks works. The code at the beginning of `Connect()` should have been called, but once it hit the first `yield` it just returned its Deferred to your caller. Later on, when the AMQP channel is acquired, that Deferred will fire.

If you want the `DoSomething()` call to... do something :) after the `c` Deferred fires, and you don't want to make `DoSomething()` into another inlineCallbacks method, then just use the Deferred in the normal way: `addCallback()` and friends. Example:

```
def DoSomething(self):
    c = self.Connect()
    c.addCallback(self.handle_getting_amqp_channel)
    c.addErrback(self.this_gets_called_if_something_went_wrong)
    return c
```

For more information on how Twisted Deferreds work, see http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Code seemes little unclear (especially 4th line indenting).
But, if I get it right **self.Connect()** call **returns** a **deferred** itself, so You'll have to use:

c = **yield** self.Connect()

in order to prevent it from running in background and do return **deferredResult** in to **c** variable.

Comment: Sorry for the indenting, i've fixed it. anyway, writing c = yield self.Connect() require that i tag DoSomething() method with @defer.inlineCallbacks and that's the whole trick, i'm looking for a way to way for deferreds in Connect() without tagging the calling method DoSomething()

Comment: @fourat
Then the only obvious way is addding some callback to **c** deferred and triggering further steps by this callback, like:
`    def doNextStep(dfr_result): do_smth()`
`    c = self.Connect()`
`    c.addCallback(doNextStep)`